# Show that the following goes to $f'(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: (-1,1) \to R$ and $f'(0)$. Suppose that $-1 < a_n < 0 < b_n < 1$ and $a_n \to 0, b_n \to 0$ Show that
$$D_n = \frac{f(b_n) - f(a_n)}{b_n - a_n}$$ goes to $f'(0)$.

This is a specific case where we need to show that $f'(0)$ is the result, not a general point where the derivative is evaluated at.

I'm not quite sure where to start. I'm not sure what $f'(0)$ is, all I'm told is that it exists. So I'm trying to show this quantity goes to that, when I don't even know what $f'(0)$ is equal to. That is throwing me off. I'm also not sure the relation to $f'(0)$ that $D_n$ has. Can anyone clarify the question for me and maybe get me started? Thank you!

Comment: You need to use the definition of $f'(0)$, i.e. $f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$.

Comment: It's not quite the same. It does help me answer, but I don't want to associate this one with that one because it is a different set up. (They have f'(a) in general and this is a specific case where f'(0).) I am taking some time now to try to use it to prove this one, but it is a different problem in my opinion.

Comment: I'm just trying to say that the problem you gave helps, but it isn't a duplicate in my opinion.

Comment: Just substitute $a$ by $0$ in the other question and you have exactly your problem. So yours is a special case of the other one, and the approach to solve them is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

\begin{align*}
\frac{f(b_n)-f(a_n)}{b_n-a_n}&=\underbrace{\frac{b_n}{b_n-a_n}}_{=1+\frac{a_n}{b_n-a_n}}\cdot \frac{f(b_n)-f(0)}{b_n}-\frac{a_n}{b_n-a_n}\cdot \frac{f(a_n)-f(0)}{a_n}\\
&=\frac{f(b_n)-f(0)}{b_n}+\frac{a_n}{b_n-a_n}\left(\frac{f(b_n)-f(0)}{b_n}-\frac{f(a_n)-f(0)}{a_n}\right)
\end{align*}

Since $\left|\frac{a_n}{b_n-a_n}\right|\leq 1$, taking $n\to \infty $ gives the wished result.

Comment: Hey there. I'm still not quite seeing where to go from there. Can you give me some more information?

Comment: @DominicBlanco: I edited my answer.

Comment: Ah I see now. That makes sense. I wasn't quite seeing where to go, but those extra steps made it clear. Thanks!

Comment: What did you get for the limit of the term $$
\frac{{f(b_n ) - f(0)}}{{b_n  - a_n }}?$$ I cannot see why it is easier to compute it than the original one?

Comment: @Gary: It's a typo. Thanks for pointing out it.

Answer (score 0):

First write
$$
D_n  - f'(0) = \frac{{b_n }}{{b_n  - a_n }}\left( {\frac{{f(b_n ) - f(0)}}{{b_n }} - f'(0)} \right) \\ + \left( {1 - \frac{{b_n }}{{b_n  - a_n }}} \right)\left( {\frac{{f(a_n ) - f(0)}}{{a_n }} - f'(0)} \right).
$$
Using the fact that
$$
0 < \frac{{b_n }}{{b_n  - a_n }} < 1.
$$
we obtain
$$
\left| {D_n  - f'(0)} \right| \le \left| {\frac{{f(b_n ) - f(0)}}{{b_n }} - f'(0)} \right| + \left| {\frac{{f(a_n ) - f(0)}}{{a_n }} - f'(0)} \right|.
$$
Thus,
\begin{align*} &
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left| {D_n  - f'(0)} \right| \le \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left| {\frac{{f(b_n ) - f(0)}}{{b_n }} - f'(0)} \right| + \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left| {\frac{{f(a_n ) - f(0)}}{{a_n }} - f'(0)} \right|
\\ &
 \le \left| {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{f(b_n ) - f(0)}}{{b_n }} - f'(0)} \right| + \left| {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{f(a_n ) - f(0)}}{{a_n }} - f'(0)} \right|
\\ &
 = \left| {f'(0) - f'(0)} \right| + \left| {f'(0) - f'(0)} \right| = 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: Hey there. Hmm, I'm still not quite seeing where to go from there. And where did the f'(0) come from? I'm not sure how you put it into the expression. Can you show all of the steps?

Comment: I subtracted $f'(0)$ from $D_n$. Why should not I do that? We know that it exists.